# Crear sombra a un bloque css en radio

Tags: html, css, radio

Como es posible agregarle sombras a un objeto pero en un radio especifico con css

Comment: Que has intentado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hola agrega esto en tu bloque deseado

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 3px 11px 43px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 11px 43px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 3px 11px 43px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```

Los valores corresponden a los siguientes valores.

Ancho,Altura, **Radio de sombra, Radio de propagación**, Color de sombra

avísame si no soy lo suficiente explicito saludos

Comment: Eso es exactamente lo que buscaba gracias

Comment: Perfecto me alegra saber eso